How can I cut the nosing off a precast masonry stair tread?
Right now it looks like this.
The type of stone that I am planning to install is described in this document. How can I cut that nose? Is it reinforced with metal ? I will need an angle grinder or masonry saw to cut my tiles anyway.


This was cut easily with a 7" dry circular saw with a stone blade (not a continuous one)
Most difficult part was to keep it parallel with the edge, avoid shaving to little and avoid getting into the slab (cut just the nose)

You could try the manual approach, a lump hammer and a bolster
If you put those on top there water will be trapped against the threshold.

Not a lot of water gets thete..the porch has a roof above.I could leave a small gap there which I could fill up with small size decorative stones. That gap will dry out the neab by stones and the thresold

Score it 1/4" or so with a diamond wheel (angle grinder, etc.), then gently tap it with a hammer. It'll crack right off on your score line. Clean up any lumps with the grinder.
