Porch with precast concrete step -what type of stones should I ask for when I order them?
Here is the porch in question

I am planning to use this stone
https://www.banasstones.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Salt-Pepper.pdf
They say it comes in Coping, Treads, Risers, Steps, Pier Caps and and so on
Besides the regular rectangular stones (planning to use what they call a random pattern) what other types of stones do I need to ask for ?
Here are the dimensions if you need them to advise me


What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to replace the existing step?

No I want to cover the step and the porch with the same stone

I think you're gonna have a hell of a time getting a tread that will wrap over the existing bullnose.  Unless you grind that off.

Yeah I have another question posted here about exactly that https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/302387/porch-with-one-precast-step-i-am-planning-to-install-1-granit-stone-over-the/302459#302459
